# Google BigQuery: Dataset not found when saving query results to table

Tags: google-bigquery

- I just ran a query in Google BigQuery. It produced just over 10 million results.
- BigQuery tells me that I cannot save query results that big directly as CSV, JSON, etc. I can only save it to a table.
- So I try to save it to a table, using the new UI, Google automatically fills in the "Project name" and "Dataset name". I have tried random table names as well as created a new table and tried to save there.

Every time I get an error:

> Not found: Dataset ethereum-account-balances:Eth_Account_Balances_Dataset

Where Ethereum-Account-Balances is the project name and Eth_Account_Balances_Dataset is the Dataset name

I have already created this dataset and confirmed it works. Even re-ran the query after creating the new data set.

Anyone has seen this before?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of what you are doing in the webUI

Comment: When you are prompted the dialog asking where you want to save to a new table, after some tests, the only way I get this error is by entering a dataset that indeed does not exist. That is, perhaps there might be a typo in the dataset name?

Answer (score 4):

The new dataset must be in the same location as the dataset whose tables are referenced in the query.

Reference - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#limitations_on_copying_tables

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to save the new BigQuery table in a different dataset of the original table.

What I did to get around this was:

1 - Saved a new BigQuery table in the same dataset or the original table
2 - Copied this new table to the other dataset, using copy table functionality